# SVN merge previous revision into working copy

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

If

- I'm working on an SVN branch at revision 5.
- I make a change, commit to create revisions r6.
- Revert back to r5 as r6 introduced problems, and commit, creating r7
- Continue working on r7, eventually committing changes up to r10

How do I merge the changes made in r6 back into my working copy?

I've tried

```
svn merge -r5:6 .
```

and

```
svn merge -r5:HEAD .
```

Both of which seem to do nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
svn merge --ignore-ancestry -r5:6 .
```

or using newer syntax:

```
svn merge --ignore-ancestry -c6 .
```

b.t.w.: I recommend to always specify what files you want to work with instead of "."

Comment: This works perfectly with Subversion 1.7.19, thanks!

Comment: I agree, this is the correct answer to the question. Thank you Midis.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a relatively recent svn release, you can use:

```
svn merge -c -6 .
```

(or the specific file(s) you would like to revert, rather than '.')

This is a shorthand for:

```
svn merge -r6:5 .
```

so if your on an older subversion release (prior to 1.6.x) you can use this syntax.

This may introduce properties into your repository (svn:mergeinfo, if memory serves), at least if you perform the merge on a whole directory. reverting a change to a single file, or set of files, does not affect properties. If you don't want these properties added to your repository, you may need to fall back to a patch (automated or manual).

Comment: Does not work. Subversion does nothing. Answer also seems wrong to me `-c -6` is supposed to undo the r6 changeset. But we want to reintroduce the r6 changeset. Answer from @Midis works.

Answer (score 2):

I am not too familiar with command line svn. But in case the correct usage does not get you the result you want here is what I would try:

1. Create a patch out of revision r6 (differences between r6 and r5).
2. Apply it on the working copy.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered this and went with `svn diff -r5:6 > patch.diff` `patch -p0 < patch.diff` in the end. I would still be interested to hear if anybody knows a way to do this through svn.

Comment: I do the same, just re-apply a diff file.

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing the revision that merged out the initial revert.

e.g.  Instead of svn merge -r 5:6 try
svn merge -r 7:6 .

Answer (score 0):

You could revert.  Create a tag.  Once you are done, you can merge changes from the tag to the branch you are working in.